# Count Number of Pages in PDF Files of a folder

Tags: pdf, count, directory

How can I get the total numbers of pages of pdfs in (sub)folders?

I like to have something in return like this:

```
c:\pdfs\path1 83
c:\pdfs\path2 12
c:\pdfs\path2\subfolder 3
etc.
```

With this code below I can get the total of pages of each pdf file. But that is not what I need. I want to get the total of each folder.

```
REM PDF-Pages.cmd
@echo off
del output.txt
for /r %1 %%f in (*.pdf) do pdfinfo.exe -meta "%%f" >out.txt & echo "%%f",, | tr.exe -d "\r\n" >>output.txt & find "Pages:" out.txt | tr.exe -d "\r\n\055\056\072[:alpha:][:space:]" >>output.txt & echo , | tr.exe -d "\r\n" >>output.txt & find "File size:" out.txt | tr.exe -d "\055\056\072[:space:][:alpha:]" >>output.txt & echo. >>output.txt
del out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job. it saves the number of pages of the pdf files in a txt file named page_num.txt

```
import os
from pdfreader import PDFDocument, SimplePDFViewer
def count_pages_in_folder(folder_path):
    total_pages = 0    
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)            
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                doc = PDFDocument(file)
                viewer = SimplePDFViewer(file)                
                for _ in viewer:
                    pass  # Iterate through pages to count them
                total_pages += viewer.current_page_number
    return total_pages
def save_result_to_file(folder_path, result):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "page_num.txt")
    with open(file_path, "w") as result_file:
        result_file.write(f"Number of pages is: {result}")
# Specify the folder_path
folder_path = r"Path/to/ur/folder/"
# Example usage:
result = count_pages_in_folder(folder_path)
save_result_to_file(folder_path, result)
print(f"Total number of pages written to {os.path.join(folder_path, 'page_num.txt')}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use Pdf Page Count - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfpagecount/; but I have no personal experience with this tool. AFAIR, something called like "Multiple PDF page count" also exists, perhaps on Sourceforge, too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?